# Why can we let a pointer of type char point to something that is const*

Tags: c++, c, constants

There is a line of code like this:`char* arr="Hello"`. I have heard that the string `Hello` is located at someplace for constant things like the value of a const variable (is that right?) . My confusion is, if that assumption is true, why can we let a pointer of type `char*` point to something that is `const`, giving people opportunity to change the const "Hello" string. I mean, isn't it unreasonable for a language like C which have type-check to allowed this happen?

Answer (score 0):

See, the `"Hello"` here is a *string literal*, but it's not `const`, by standard.

Most compilers, including `gcc`, puts the *string literals* in read only memory. Standard only mandates not to modify the *string literals.*

Quoting from `C11` standard, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.